# Неследовать поля django от другого класса

Tags: python, django

Пишу много моделей, где у каждой из них, есть одни и те же поля. Думал вынести их в отдельный класс и позже наследоваться от него, но это не работает.

```
class BasicInfo:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, name='Название')
    price = models.IntegerField(name='Цена')
    pubdate = models.DateField()
    isavailable = models.BooleanField(name='В наличии')

class Processor(models.Model, BasicInfo):
   frequency = models.CharField(max_length=200, name='Частота')
   cache = models.CharField(max_length=300, name='Кэш')

class Psu(models.Model, BasicInfo):
    watt = models.CharField(max_length=300, name='Мощность (ватт)')
```

После этого в админ панели нет полей прописанных в классе BasicInfo, в этом и заключается вопрос - почему?

Comment: попробуйте унаследовать `class BasicInfo` от `models.Model` это будет некий абстрактный класс, опишите для него `class Meta: abstract = True`  а классы `Processor` и `Psu` унаследйте ТОЛЬКО от `BasicInfo` что то типа `class Processor(BasicInfo):`